# How to import script that requires __name__ == "__main__"

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, dill

I'm pretty new to Python, this question probably shows that. I'm working on multiprocessing part of my script, couldn't find a definitive answer to my problem.

I'm struggling with one thing. When using multiprocessing, part of the code has to be guarded with if `__name__ == "__main__"`. I get that, my pool is working great. But I would love to import that whole script (making it a one big function that returns an argument would be the best). And here is the problem. First, how can I import something if part of it will only run when launched from the main/source file because of that guard? Secondly, if I manage to work it out and the whole script will be in one big function, pickle can't handle that, will use of "multiprocessing on dill" or "pathos" fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You should put the code you want to be importable *in a function*. Then *use that function* in a guarded `__name__ == '__main__'` block in your other module.

Comment: " Secondly, if I manage to work it out and the whole script will be in one big function," *the whole script doesn't have to be one giant fucntion*. In general, you want to break up your code into modular, re-usable and logically coherent parts. Yes, there might be "one function to rule them all"....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably confused with the concept. The `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard in Python exists **exactly** in order for it to be possible for all Python files to be importable.

Without the guard, a file, once imported, would have *the same behavior* as if it were the "root" program - and it would require a lot of boyler plate and inter-process comunication (like writting a "PID" file at a fixed filesystem location) to coordinate imports of the same code, including for multiprocessing.

Just leave under the guard whatever code needs to run for the root process. Everything else you move into functions that you can call from the importing code.

If you'd run "all" the script, even the part setting up the multiprocessing workers would run, and any simple job would create more workers exponentially until all machine resources were taken (i.e.: it would crash hard and fast, potentially taking the machine to an unresponsive state).

So, this is a good pattern - th "dothejob" function can call all
other functions you need, so you just need to import and call it,
either from a master process, or from any other project importing
your file as a Python module.

```py
import multiprocessing
...
def dothejob():
   ...

def start():
   # code to setup and start multiprocessing workers:
   # like:
   worker1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dothejob)
   ...
   worker1.start()
   ...
   worker1.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   start()
```

Comment: And just to belabor the point, you can call `module.start()` in another module

Comment: Thank you, this approach works great. I also realized I need to educate on classes as there is a lot of data that's shared between the functions. Thank you!