# Python's multiprocessing.Process all perfect under Unix, total failure under Windows

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

A very basic Python program using multiprocessing. It has just two imports and two function definitions. sf() is a completely trivial function. r() creates a Process with sf as the target and starts it. That's the whole thing. It works perfectly and exactly as I would expect under Unix (FreeBSD13) no matter how I enter it. Under Windows things are very different. If I put the code in a file mp.py and import mp, I can type mp.r() and everything is good. But I like to try things out interactively. When I type the exact same code absolutely verbatim into Idle and then type r(), it fails. I doubt that the process is even successfully started. Just an instant exit code of 1. I have read, on this very site, some talk about subprocesses reimporting the main module, but it is never explained. Obviously I can get around this problem just by always putting everything in a file, but there is clearly something significant going on here, and I need to understand what it is. This is the whole session:

Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

```
>>> import multiprocessing as m
>>> import time
>>> def sf():
...   print("start")
...   time.sleep(4)
...   print("stop")
... 
>>> def r():
...   p = m.Process(target = sf)
...   p.start()
...   print("Wait")
...   p.join()
...   return p
...
>>> a = r()
Wait
>>> a.exitcode
1
```

What I did: program in a .py file, import it, works as expected. Enter the same thing directly into Idle, what I got is instant failure, what I was expecting was for it to behave exactly as it did when imported from a file.

Answer (score 2):

On linux the child process is a replica of the parent process, it is a forked verison of it, when you call `target = sf`, the child process knows what `sf` is and calls it.

windows spawn a "fresh" process that is equivalent of just calling `python.exe`, it has no idea what `target = sf` even means, only the parent process does (and it doesn't relay code to the child, only the function name and its location). so when the function is in another file, the "fresh" child reads the file.

python interactive mode is known to not work well with multiprocessing, and it depends on your IDE and operating system, so if you have to use multiprocessing then run your code in non-interactive mode (script mode), and use "[import guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895094/how-to-import-script-that-requires-name-main)" in all your files.